# Change Data Capture- Get only distinct latest changes

Tags: sql-server, cdc

I am trying to find all the distinct and latest changes only from a certain change data capture table. Here is the snap shot of the table.
[image]

I tried to use this query:

```
select DISTINCT StudentUSI, sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(__$start_lsn) TransactionTime, __$operation Operation, LastModifiedDate 
from cdc.Student_CT
where __$operation in (1,2,4)
ORDER BY StudentUSI;
```

But the returned result is:

[image]

Also if I try to use GROOUP BY, it says:

> Column 'cdc.Student_CT.__$start_lsn' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Is there any other way I could just get the most latest change with respect to the StudentUSI value? 
Thank you!

Comment: You have to group by all of the columns unless you are using an aggregate function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use row_number()

```
select * from 
(select DISTINCT StudentUSI, sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time(__$start_lsn) TransactionTime, __$operation Operation, LastModifiedDate ,row_number() over(partition by StudentUSI order by LastModifiedDate desc) as rn
from cdc.Student_CT
where __$operation in (1,2,4))a where rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Can you please explain it as well. I am new to SQL queries.

Comment: row_number() applies a running, incremented number to the group defined in the `partition by` clauses, starting with the first row defined in the `order by`. So, in this statement, a row number starting with 1 and going to n will be applied to every StudentUSI, starting with the latest LastModifiedDate since the order by is descending. At the end of this statement, the where clause returns only 1 row for each StudentUSI, being the latest one. Remove the `where RN = 1` and you can see how the logic works @Skaranjit

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that really cleared the query. Awesome :D